# Strange image sizes in Chrome/GMail: should be 29px, are 27.986px

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, html-email

I've got what I think is a typical table-based EDM which contains some images (which are also links).

For some users, the images fit neatly into their table cells. For other users, there are visible gaps.

But when I say "for some users" this *doesn't* happen for me on Chrome, viewing the EDM in GMail, and it *does* happen for another user, who is using the exact same version of Chrome (35.0.1916.153) and also viewing it in GMail.

When I inspect the `img` element, in my browser they are 29px. In the problem browser, they are 27.986px, which of course isn't even possible.

There aren't any percentages involved in their sizes.

Here's what it looks like in code inspector

[image: http://i.imgur.com/2oLHOms.png]

Here is sample code:

```
<td width="29" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <a target="_blank" href="something">
        <img src="something.jpg" width="29" height="29" alt="something" 
        border="0"  style="display:block;outline-style:none;text-decoration:none;-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;border-style:none;">
    </a>
</td>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You've probably found an answer to this problem already, but if you have not found a solution. It maybe that the padding and spacing is still there. Sometimes style tags and elements are removed from the email.

Try adding:

cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"

to the table tag.

Comment: I certainly haven't found an answer, thanks for your input though. The table already had all of those things set to zero. Did you notice the bit about the browser being identical and the client being gmail in both cases? That was the really puzzling thing.